# Can't apply custom layout update to block?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, xml, static-block, layout-update

I have a static block identifier named '`can_content_block_ideas`' and within that block the following template file is being called `{{block type='core/template' template='can/home/featured.phtml}}`

Now, that template file contains the class (`.featured-product-price`) that I want to remove using the Custom Layout Update feature in Magento located here: `Categories > Custom Design`.

Below is the XML I am trying to use but I just can't figure out how to get it to work.

```
<reference name="can_content_block_ideas">
    <block type="core/template" name="hide.content">
      <action method="setText">
        <text>
           <![CDATA[
                <style type="text/css">
                    .featured-product-price { display: none; }
                </style>
            ]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to create a new template, then you remove your class that you don't need and you set this new one in your cms block.

1. `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/can/home/featured2.phtml`
2. cms > static block > `{{block type='core/template' template='can/home/featured2.phtml}}`

Don't set your css like this within the xml, if you want to remove this class just for this static block and this page i guess, you have to get the layout handle + the class like:

```
.catalog_product_view .featured-product-price {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is wrong

Try below code

```
<reference name="head">
   <block type="core/text" name="custom_css">
      <action method="setText">
          <text><![CDATA[
             <style  type="text/css">
                .featured-product-price { display: none; }
             </style> ]]>
        </text>
    </action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

try and let me know